# TProtocolException: Missing version in readMessageBegin, old client

Tags: java, hadoop, thrift

I tried to run a thrift Java client built against thrift 0.9.0

You can find the code here:
https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/thrift/DemoClient.java

In the classpath, there is libthrift-0.9.0.jar
I got the following:

> scanning tables...
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.security.PrivilegedActionException:
>   org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolException: Missing version in
>   readMessageBegin, old client?     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.DemoClient.main(DemoClient.java:81)
>   Caused by: org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolException: Missing
>   version in readMessageBegin, old client?  at
>   org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:213)
>     at
>   org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.generated.Hbase$Client.recv_getTableNames(Hbase.java:903)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.generated.Hbase$Client.getTableNames(Hbase.java:891)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.DemoClient.run(DemoClient.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.DemoClient.access$000(DemoClient.java:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.DemoClient$1.run(DemoClient.java:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.DemoClient$1.run(DemoClient.java:82)

Can someone give hint on what might have caused the above ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Version mismatch with hbase.  Your hbase client lib is older than the server's lib you are connecting to.  What HBase version are you compiling under?

> mvn dependency:tree

will list out the dependencies for the project.

Comment: Feel free to post the output if you need help.

Comment: DemoClient came from the same lib directory for the hbase 1.1.2 build. It is hard to see how the client got out of sync with server which uses the same build. thrift version in pom.xml is 0.9.0

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue after upgrading a server to Cloudera Hadoop 5.10 from CDH 5.3. For me, the key was changing this property to false:

```
<property>
<name>hbase.regionserver.thrift.http</name>
<value>false</value>
</property>
```

It seems that the HTTP protocol was added in CDH5.4.0 and my server settings had this setting to true. This is incompatible with the TBinaryProtocol of my client.